# Having issues to import imblearn python package on Jupyter notebook on Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, imblearn

I wanted to install imbalanced-learn using pip install imbalanced-learn. Then I have tried import

```
from imblearn.ensemble import EasyEnsembleClassifier
```

This import gave me the following error. I did try with uninstall imbalanced-learn and re-install imbalanced-learn, but it didn't help.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_joblib_parallel_args' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' (C:\Users\Jishan\anaconda3\envs\summerprojects\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py)
```

I also tried

```
pip: pip install -U imbalanced-learn
anaconda: conda install -c glemaitre imbalanced-learn
```

They were not helpful as well. I was using Anaconda virtual environment. I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60293404/8508004) suggests your scikit learn and imbalanced-learn packages out of of sync. If you care about scikit-learn working with code you already have, you may want to use your Anaconda make a new environment all together to see if you can force upgrade to these packages to more current for each and see if import improves. I would stick with using conda and not pip **as much as you can** since you are using Anaconda. It will lessen headaches such as these if you aren't using multiple package mangers in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

- *conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn* to update documentation
- *sudo pip3 install imblearn* to install imblearn

Comment: I did that, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

on command prompt : pip3 install imblearn
on anaconda !pip3 install imblearn